# VS2010 relative paths in local URL references in comment lines

Tags: visual-studio-2010, path, comments, relative-path

In my source code I would like to add a comment statement as follows:

// "*file://explaningPicture.jpg*"

In VS2010 such a line becomes a hyperlink, which you can open with **[CTRL][CLICK]**
But it only seems to work when I specify a hard coded path

// "*file://C:/mypictures/explaningPicture.jpg*"

But since my explainingPicture.jpg is part of my project documentation, it is in the VS2010 project, and I really would like to use a relative path.

But what should it be? What is the current directory in a VS2010 project within VS2010?

Answer (score 1):

Does not look like it currently can be done according to [Elegentin Xie MSFT](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/594f9cda-e06a-4172-acd5-37213d9d805b/visual-studio-2012-hyperlinks-in-c-comments).

> When searching header files or .lib files, we can control the relative path to a certain scope. Unfortunately, I have not got a way of dealing the relative path in comment section.

I started a [User Voice suggestion](http://visualstudio.uservoice.com/forums/121579-visual-studio/suggestions/4994655-allow-relative-paths-for-external-hyperlinks-in-co) that this be added to Visual Studio - feel free to vote for it.

Related questions specifically about images
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19369696/how-to-put-link-with-relative-path-in-net-comment) and [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241085/how-to-use-file-references-in-comments-base-address-placeholder)
seem to benefit from [Sergey Vlasov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/84507/sergey-vlasov)'s suggestion of [ImageComment](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments), an extension which apparently displays the image itself in visual studio and can use relative paths.