# How to use file references in comments - base address ? placeholder?

Tags: visual-studio-2012

When I type `file://someDir/image.png` in Visual Studio source code ***comment*** (2012, c#, for that matter), I guess it's a relative path. So what is the base address? is there a way to set, for instance, current project as the base address (or even use some kind of placeholder like `%PROJECT%` or something similar) ?

I want to use image to explain complicated idea, like:

`// take a look at:`[`file://ThisExplainsItBetter.png`](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/793d16d0-235a-439a-91df-4ce7c721df12/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ImageComments](https://github.com/lukesdm/image-comments) extension for Visual Studio can display images and use relative paths.

Answer (score 0):

What you're asking for is not really possible, as there is no comment pre-processor for C#, or any other language that I can think of. The source code is turned into the executable, but the comments are ignored.

In addition, such a pre-processor would inadvertently edit your code before compilation, or do some other spooky stuff, which may change your executable's logic.

Comment: It's not a `C#` compiler issue, it's related to the IDE (maybe adding the `C#` tag is a mistake). I just want to be able to click on the "hyper-link" (as the `file://` prefix makes it a click-able hyperlink when in a `Visual Studio` comment block) and then see the linked image/resource

Answer (score -3):

You can go with may be it will help you

**string startupPath = System.IO.Directory.GetCurrentDirectory();**

**string startupPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory;**

**Or if you have Image folder inside your repository you can use "../../" or "~/" 
It will get file from your project root.**