# How to put link with relative path in .NET comment

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012, hyperlink, comments

I am doing some calculations in .NET and would like to supplement them with a link to an image with the original calculations, taken from my notebook. I'm using CVS revision control, and have elected to put the image file under revision control as well, in the \Resource directory of my project. I have added it as a resource in the project as well, not sure if this will be of any use.

I would like the file to be launchable from a comment in the code by other developers, much like a http link is handled by Visual Studio:

```
' http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask
```

which will launch the webpage in a VS tab. I can put the full path to the file relative to my machine, which will work on my machine but not somewhere else, since the CVS repo will be in a different location. i.e.

```
' file://C:\<pathToCheckoutFolder>\Resources\file.jpg
```

where `pathToCheckoutFolder` will vary from workstation to workstation.

I am hoping there is a solution which will use a relative path to the project directory. I'd rather not place the file on our server, and link with a UNC path (which should work), since I'll lose revision control over the document.

Comment: How variable would be the path from one workstation to the other? Bear in mind that knowing the whole path is required to execute any action. Relative paths come from the assumption that part of the path is known and thus does not need to be inputted.

Comment: My checkout folder has my username in it - as could anybody's. But since it's under revision control, I know it will be in the `Project folder\Resources\`. A solution based on that would be ideal

Comment: With "Project folder" you mean the folder containing the whole solution? (*.sln file + folder with all the project files)

Comment: Not exactly, this is happening inside a project which compiles to a class library, so I didn't bother making a solution for it. Visual Studio uses the macro `$(ProjectPath)` inside project>>compile>>build events, but it doesn't seem to be recognized in comments.

Comment: Sorry but I don't have any idea :)

Comment: See similar question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19241085/how-to-use-file-references-in-comments-base-address-placeholder